# RXDB Application and data storage size issue

Tags: mongodb, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, offlineapps, rxdb

I'm working on a web app using RXDB as a client side database and MongoDB as a server side database.

Currently, local RXDB browser databases contain exactly the same data as the server side db.

This could become an issue in the future when the size of the server db is too big for users PCs.

Is it possible to configure such an app so that at a certain point in time, only part of the total data set in the server side db is store in client RXDB databases?